# 404 Controllers Not Found when Spring MVC app is published to tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm kinda new with Spring MVC and now I'm stuck; my app works perfectly in localhost but when I deploy the WAR file to the Tomcat server it just returns an HTTP 404 for all the spring controllers/APIs.

Note that views work just fine, but if I go to Chrome console I can see a lot of 404 errors.

This works:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
```

This does not:

```
http://myServerName:8080/myapp/hello
```

This is my test controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(Model model) {
        log.debug("hello gets hit!");
        return "{'message':'Hello Andy'}";
    }

}
```

It seems that this is related with the routing, but I'm lost.

Comment: Define views work just fine?

Comment: When `localhost:8080` works, which webserver are you running? It would help if you showed your server's catalina.out file.

Comment: You need the name of the WAR in the URL.  Host name is insufficient: http://host:port/war/ is the root of your URLs.

Comment: Sorry I did the update, yes I'm using the war name, and it is  Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

Comment: Locally I'm using jetty

Comment: When I say "Views work just fine", I mean all those defined this way: registry.addViewController("index").setViewName("index"); in  the WebConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else is facing this, I found that the issue was happening cause tomcat was taking java 1.7 as default setting, just needed to go and change the version to 1.8 in the config file and that's it the apis are now working just fine.

Comment: which config file did you update? I'm having a similar issue.I have `/etc/default/tomcat` pointed to java8.

Comment: sudo vim /etc/default/tomcat7